# $\mathcal{F}=\{S\subset E: \exists A\in \mathcal{B}(S\supset A)\}$ + $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{B}$ is a filter base.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Some definition:
$E$ is a nonempty set, some subset of $E$ consist a set $\mathcal{F}$ called a filter if it satisfied the following condition:

1. if $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A \subset G \subset E$, then $G \in \mathcal{F}$.
2. if $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$,then $A\cap B \in \mathcal{F}$
3. $E\in \mathcal{F}$
4. $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$

---

$E$ is a nonempty set, some subset of $E$ consist a set $\mathcal{B}$ called a filter base if it satisfied the following condition:

1. if $A,B\in\mathcal{B}$,then $A\cap B\supset\exists C\in \mathcal{B}$.
2. $\mathcal{B}\not=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{B}$

---

show that:
$\mathcal{B}$ is a filter base if and only if $$\mathcal{F}=\{S\subset E: \exists A\in \mathcal{B}(S\supset A)\}$$ is a filter.

the $\Rightarrow$ is straightforward:

- if $\mathcal{B}$ is a filter base, $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$
- $\mathcal{B}\not=\emptyset \Rightarrow $$\exists A \in \mathcal{B}$ and $A \subset E$ $\Rightarrow E \in \mathcal{F}$
- if $G \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow \exists A \in \mathcal{B}(G\supset A)$, and $G \subset H \subset E \Rightarrow A\subset H \Rightarrow H \in \mathcal{F}$
- if $F,G \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\exists A \in \mathcal{B}(F\supset A),\exists B \in \mathcal{B}(G\supset B)$, and $A\cap B\supset\exists C \in \mathcal{B}$, and $C \subset F \cap G$,$\Rightarrow F\cap G \in \mathcal{F}$.

**I have got a trouble when I try  $\Leftarrow$.**

$\mathcal{F}$ is a filter, if $S_1, S_2 \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\exists A_1,A_2\in\mathcal{B}(S_1\supset A_1,S_2\supset A_2)$, then $$A_1\cap A_2 \subset S_1\cap S_2 \in \mathcal{F}$$, from this I can deduce  $S_1\cap S_2\supset \exists A_3 \in \mathcal{B}$. But I can't prove $A_1\cap A_2 \supset \exists A \in \mathcal{B}$. It makes me dispirited.

Answer (score 1):

First observe that $\mathcal B \subseteq \mathcal F$. As $\mathcal F \neq \emptyset$, there is some $A \in \mathcal F$ and thus some $B \in \mathcal B$ with $B \subseteq A$, i.e. $\mathcal B \neq \emptyset$. As $\emptyset \not \in \mathcal F$, we get $\emptyset \not \in \mathcal B$.

Finally, let $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal B$. Then $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal F$ and $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal F$, because $\mathcal F$ is a filter. By the definition of $\mathcal F$ there is now some $B \in \mathcal B$ with $B \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$ and we have shown that $\mathcal B$ is a filter base.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting in the wrong place. You want to start with arbitrary $A_1,A_2\in\mathscr{B}$ and show that there is some $A_3\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $A_3\subseteq A_1\cap A_2$. Clearly $A_1,A_2\in\mathscr{F}$, so $A_1\cap A_2\in\mathscr{F}$. Can you finish it now?